# Как корректно создать sql запрос с Join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Имеется таблица товаров (обувь) и их доступности:

```
Goods:
 id
 title
 description
 price

Availability:
 goodsId
 size
 count
```

Вопрос в следующем: мне нужно одной строкой вывести все поля товара и в эту строку добавить все доступные размеры с кол-вом на складе.

Comment: На SQL это невозможно. количество колонок возвращаемых запросом не может создаваться динамически. количество колонок всегда жестко зашито в запросе. такую задачу надо решать на клиенте, собирая горизонтальные данные по мере чтения вертикально расположенных из БД

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте группирование результатов и обработку их с помощью GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT Goods.id, Goods.titile, Goods.description, Goods.price, GROUP_CONCAT(Availability.size, ":", Availability.count, "\n") available FROM Goods JOIN Availability ON Availability.goodsId = Goods.id GROUP BY Goods.id;
```

В столбце available у Вас будут размеры и количество через ":", а разделителем между размерами будет выступать переход на новую строку.

Также можно использовать запрос, который будет возвращать несколько результатов одного варианта (в случае нескольких размеров) и групировать данные по id надо будет непосредственно получателем в каком-нибудь ассоциативном массиве.

```
SELECT Goods.id, Goods.titile, Goods.description, Goods.price, Availability.size,Availability.count FROM Goods JOIN Availability ON Availability.goodsId = Goods.id
```